# PDF not downloading in Chrome

Tags: html, .htaccess, google-chrome

I have integrated the following page [click here](http://www.fluotics.com/new/index.php/support-page) into expression engine. Only certain PDFs will download in chrome, as demonstrated in the link above, whereas with Firefox users are able to download all PDFs on the page. I've been searching through various expression engine forums and followed instruction such as disabling my XSS Filter and re uploading all my PDFs. I'm also running this latest version of EE and i've tried downloading PDFs logged out of the super-admin account.

I'm not sure whether this is a browser issue or an issue with expression engine, has anyone come across this problem before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're delivering those as type `application/octet-stream`.  You'll want to start, then, by delivering them as `application/pdf`.  Add this to your .htaccess (if you don't have access to you Apache config or can't reload your Apache config):

```
AddType application/pdf .pdf
```

Comment: hmmm... do i remove application/octet-stream? i still can't get it to work

Comment: Yes, you should remove or comment-out all `AddType application/octet-stream .pdf` in .htaccess and Apache configs (remember to reload or restart if the latter).  It looks from here like this setting has been changed properly.  Which links work and which don't?

Answer (score 2):

This is an apparently common issue with chrome.  But, since chrome is up to date with HTML5, we can use the shiny new `download` attribute!

`<a href="http://www.domain.com/painful.pdf">Broken</a>`

`<a href="http://www.domain.com/painful.pdf" download="notsopainful">Works</a>`

Comment: This actually worked for me - I was only seeing the issue when trying to download a pdf on Chrome Mobile Android 4.3